# Input type radio se selecciona al segundo click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en React con typescript y Redux Toolkit, y tengo un componente conformado por tres inputs type radio, que cuando se clickean llaman a un dispatch para ejecutar una acción de un reducer. Se supone que el input que se encuentre seleccionado va a depender de un valor que tengo en mi store, pero está sucediendo que cuando hago click en uno de los inputs, este se selecciona es al segundo click, y no al instante de seleccionarlo. Estuve debuggeando, y encuentro que cuando se hace click en uno de los inputs, el valor en el estado se actualiza correctamente con el valor del input, sin embargo en el componente no se refleja la selección del input sino hasta que se le vuelve a dar click al input (click por 2da vez al mismo input). No sé cómo solucionar esto

```
    SetTransactionType: (state: IPayment, action: PayloadAction<TransactionType>):void =>{
      state.paymentDetail.transactionType = action.payload;
    }
```

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../store";
import { SetTransactionType } from "../../store/reducers";

interface ITransactionTypeProps {
  className?: string;
}

export const TransactionTypeComponent = ({className}: ITransactionTypeProps):JSX.Element => {

  const { paymentDetail } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.payment);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch(e.currentTarget.value) {
      case 'pago-movil':
        dispatch(SetTransactionType('pago-movil'));
        break;
      case 'transferencia':
        dispatch(SetTransactionType('transferencia'));
        break;
      default:
        dispatch(SetTransactionType('deposito'));
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <div className='flex gap-3'>
        <input type='radio' name='pago-movil' id='pago-movil' checked={paymentDetail.transactionType === 'pago-movil'} onChange={handleChange} value='pago-movil'/>
        <label>Pago móvil</label>
      </div>
      <div className='flex gap-3'>
        <input type='radio' name='transferencia' id='transferencia' checked={paymentDetail.transactionType === 'transferencia'} onChange={handleChange} value='transferencia'/>
        <label>Transferencia</label>
      </div>
      <div className='flex gap-3'>
        <input type='radio' name='deposito' id='deposito' checked={paymentDetail.transactionType === 'deposito'} onChange={handleChange} value='deposito'/>
        <label>Depósito</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```